# Pushing rational numbers

Tags: ruby, numbers, rational-numbers

I have to make class `NumberSet`, which is a container for different kinds of numbers that can include only numbers that are not already in it.

```
class NumberSet
  include Enumerable

  def initialize
    @arr=[]
  end
  def each (&block)
    @arr.each do |member|
      block.call (member)
    end
  end
  def << number
    @arr<<number if @arr.include?(number) == false
  end
end
```

This code truncates the Rational numbers. For example, `(22/7)` should not equal `(3/1)`.

```
mine=NumberSet.new
mine<<Rational(22/7)
# => [(3/1)]
mine<<3.0
# => nil
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: Styling point: Instead of `@arr<<number if @arr.include?(number) == false` do `@arr << number unless @arr.include?(number)`

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not just using Ruby's `set` library?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your usage of Rational is wrong. Should be

```
mine << Rational(22, 7)
```

Comment: Yep I discovered my mistake, silly me. Thank you for the answer.

Comment: "22/7".to_r is another option.

Answer (score 1):

With the newest Ruby, you should do:

```
mine << 22/7r
```

Comment: Should or could? There's a big difference :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Should. Because that is less confusing and is concise.

Comment: I don't like this new syntax, but, fortunately, I never had to deal with rationals. So I don't really care. :)

Comment: @Sergio, you are missing out on a lot in life by limiting yourself to irrational numbers.